# How to modify the contents of all the alive buffers in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am planning on the following steps to get the output of the question.

1. get the list of buffers and iterate on it
2. get the contents of the buffers using the buffer name obtained in step 1.
3. change the contents and overwrite the buffer.

The (buffer-list) fn output is very confusing. It shows like 
(# ...)

I dont understand what does # < and * stands for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of `buffer-list` is a list of *buffer objects*.

Functions dealing with a specific buffer will typically accept a buffer object as an argument:

```
(buffer-name (car (buffer-list)))
```

The `#<...>` syntax is explained here:

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(elisp) Printed Representation")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

I can't imagine why you'd want to modify *all* buffers (remember this includes the minibuffer, possibly some internal-use buffers, various others like *Help*, *Messages*, and maybe some read-only buffers), but you could use the following as the basis:

```
(let ((buffers (buffer-list)))
  (while (car buffers)
    (set-buffer (car buffers))
    (let ((contents (save-restriction (widen) (buffer-string))))
      [do something with contents] )
    (setq buffers (cdr buffers))))
```